# Flask-Script option is required before command

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

I want to carry out the following in Terminal:

```
python manage.py runserver -c True
```

with the code below:

**manage.py:**

```
from my_app import app

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_option('-c', '--config', dest='config', required=False)

manager.run()
```

When I enter the command in terminal, I receive an error stating:

```
usage: manage.py [-c C] [-?] {shell,runserver} ...
manage.py: error: too many arguments
```

so it requires me to place the argument `-c` before `runserver` for some reason. Although this is a minor issue, I assumed that best practice was that all arguments should be after the command. Why is the argument required before the command in my case? Thanks.

Comment: Because you've added the argument to the manager app, not a particular subcommand.

Comment: @dim right, but then there is no other method to adding arguments to the default runserver command?

Comment: Not that I've tried. Besides, if runserver doesn't know about the option already, how would it do anything with it?